# How to check if a port (input) is high? PIC16 C program

Tags: pic, xc8, proteus

I cannot understand why my code won't work.  It works when I set the condition `PORTA == 0x00` but not when `PORTA == 0x01`. How do you check if a bit is high? Below is my code and my schematic (Crystal frequency is 4MHz).

```c
#include<xc.h>

void main(){
    int cnt;
    int delay_cnt;
    TRISA = 1;                 // PortA as input
    TRISB = 0;                // PortB as output
    PORTB = 0x00;            // Initialize LED as off


    for(;;){                // Infinite loop
        if(PORTA == 0x01){
            for(cnt=0;cnt<3;cnt++){
                PORTB = 0x01; // Turns on LED
                for(delay_cnt=0;delay_cnt<10000;delay_cnt++); 
                PORTB = 0x00; // Turns off LED
                for(delay_cnt=0;delay_cnt<10000;delay_cnt++); 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: If you have a debugger/tracer, view the value of `PORTA` register before and after the button pushing.

Answer (score 1):

In this case `if (PORTA == 0x01)`, you are checking the whole port (8 bit).
If you want to check just bit 0 from the port use this:

```
if (PORTAbits.RA0 == 1){
```

or

```
if (PORTA & 0x01){
```